# Sort post by category using HTML Select tag

Tags: posts, categories, query

Good day wordpress dev. Just want to ask if it is possible to sort, filter or query post using HTML Select tag? This is the design I am trying to develop.

http://i255.photobucket.com/albums/hh140/testament1234/sort_post_zps7415de5e.png

I have been searching for solutions on how to accomplish this and the closest thing i can find is the Select query solution.

Sorry if i cannot provide any code right now since i'm still searching for a solution and this kind of feature is unknown to me

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What sorting algorithm or filter to use is up to you. Please explain your problem better, in its current form, the question is too broad.

Comment: For you research effort this kind of search (with results narrowed down by some multi-option criteria) is often called "faceted"